# Flutter iOS firebaseMessaging doesn't handle RemoteMessages without Notification block

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I intercept messages as follows:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');
  
});
```

I send messages from the server as follows:

```
Message message = Message.builder()
                    .setToken("TOKEN")
                    .putAllData(payload)
                    .setApnsConfig(
                            ApnsConfig.builder()
                                    .setAps(Aps.builder()
                                            .setContentAvailable(true)
                                            .build())
                                    .build())
                    .build();
```

On Android everything works fine, but on iOS the message is displayed only if I add a "notification" block on the server. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with version 11 of firebase_messaging library. When I rolled back to 10.0.9 it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up apple configuration, thats why you stacked into blockings

Comment: What do you mean? On server side I added Apns config with content-available: true. Also I added all certificates.